# Using XSL, XSLT - How do you reproduce or print the XML document that it is transforming?

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

Without access to it the XML file or data, how can you reproduce a copy of the XML file that the web page is transforming using XSL?

I have access to the xml.config file which contains XSL code.  I've found solutions that outputs all the data of the XML file, but its not helpful because it's a wall of values.  It doesn't contain the xml tags and doesn't provide the node tree.

Comment: sungod000, What do you mean by "a wall of values"? Sounds too poetic and thus too ambiguous...

Comment: sungod000, If you want this question to really mean something, you need to provide a sample XML document (as small as possible, please), and the exact wanted result from the transformation. Then if necessary, explain the rules for obtaining the wanted result from the provided XML document.

Comment: show a picture or dump of part of this 'wall of code'.

Comment: Note: xslt transforms are not (in the general case) reversible.  It's hard to understand exactly what you are asking here.  What is your input data?

Comment: @AlexBrown Pardon my lack of correct terminology, I'm new to this, and trying to fix an issue for someone.  Also, you're right, I should have given example or image of what I was talking about.

Comment: Still, what is your input data?  is it the output html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document, for example this one:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted result -- the same XML document -- is produced:**

```
<nums>
   <num>01</num>
   <num>02</num>
   <num>03</num>
   <num>04</num>
   <num>05</num>
   <num>06</num>
   <num>07</num>
   <num>08</num>
   <num>09</num>
   <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, but I think I've used this before, where its printing what looks like all the values in a wall of text.  No xml tags or tree structure.

Comment: @sungod000, When you say "I've used this before", this is called "anecdotical evidence". XSLT is a strict discipline -- you *must* provide a counter example. I will help you here -- you *can't* do this. What you describe is possible only if you had `<xsl:output method="text"/>` but this isn't the case with my solution.

Comment: My mistake!  Sorry, I was only looking at the page.  I forgot to look at the developer tools that show the DOM.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dimitre: Some web browsers will just treat an XML document as if it were supposed to be an html document, and on not recognizing the elements (because they're not html ones), will just display the contents of the text nodes.

Comment: sungod000, In addition to this, if you want the XML to be displayed "pretty-printed" by a web-browser -- you just feed this to the browser and get an indented result, usually with syntax hi-lighting. If you need a transformation that produces the HTML for such pretty browser display, they are all available -- for example the IE's default stylesheet. I would recommend also to have a look and use the XSLT transformation used by the XPath Visualizer -- it produces output similar to that of IE: http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, If you just need to see the data, you could use something simple like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name())" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',name(),'=&quot;',.,'&quot;')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This won't output comments or processing instructions, but it's good enough if you just need to see the data and the structure of the document. If you need something more elaborate, you can probably find an xslt that converts an XML document to a web page that displays it. I've got one that's a work in progress here: http://www.flynn1179.net/xml/DisplayXml.xslt. I use this on my website, but there's probably something better around.

Comment: THanks Flynn1179, this worked too but Dimetre gave me correct answer first, I was just too noob to realize it.

Comment: Heh, if you can view the DOM like then yeah, copying the document as is is good enough. I was expecting you might not have the access to view the DOM like that.